# Open userform when click in speficic column in table and read row values

Tags: excel, vba

**System Description:** I have created an inventory manager in Excel that tracks the quantity, location, and who is renting any given asset. In the master table of inventory *MasterInventory* on Sheet 1 (named *Inventory*), it shows all information including a column *Renter*- the person who is renting the asset, blank if no one is renting it.

I have already created the userform *Checkout_Form* and it works as intended but it needs to know which row was clicked in the *Renter* column to capture the asset's ID number to log the renting process.

**Problem:** When I click in the *Renter* column, I want *Checkout_Form* to open to allow the user to fill input based on the asset (which is reliant which row of the column was selected).

**My Question**: How do I create a link of some kind in *Renter* column that, when clicked, will open *Checkout_Form* and pass the asset ID (based on the row it's in) to it.

**My Attempt:** I have tried to use a macro for *Worksheet_SelectionChange* and check if the *Target* variable falls in the *Renter* column but I can't get it to work; it seems to be a problem with the column range I give and then I still don't know how to read the row's values.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DesiredRange As Range
    Set DesiredRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MasterInventory[Renter]")
    If Intersect(Target, DesiredRange) Is Nothing Then Checkout_Form.Show

End Sub
```

A button at the top of the sheet has not worked for me because there's no way to know which asset I'm currently working with.

Comment: You can send the row number in a hidden text field on the user form.  For example, create a textbox, lets say TextBox1, on the userform and set it's property to visible = false.  Before you open the userform, set the value of that textbox to the target.row.  Like this:  (Lets say the userform name is UserForm1.)  The code is:  UserForm1.TextBox1.caption = Target.Row: UserForm1.Show.  That way the procedures in your userform can utilize the row number simply by using clng(TextBox1.Value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an error when I tried to name a range "MasterInventory[Renter]".  So in my test I used a range named "Renter."  Try the following code in your sheet module and the bottom code in your userform module to see how to transfer a row number to your userform.  You'll have to change the range name.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DesiredRange As Range
    Set DesiredRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MasterInventory[Renter]")
    If Not Intersect(Target, DesiredRange) Is Nothing Then
        Checkout_Form.TextBox1.value = Target.Row
        Checkout_Form.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

And put the following your form module:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    MsgBox "Row: " & Me.TextBox1.value
End Sub
```

Comment: Threw an error, the debugger says that "DesiredRange = Nothing". Again insinuating that 'Renter' is not a column on my table.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant when I said you'll have to change the range name to the name on your table.  You also need to add the invisible textbox to your form, which may have a different name then TextBox1.  That's another name you may have to change.  We can only provide the logic.  You have to change the names to suit your own app.

Comment: FYI - I changed the Answer above to reflect your specific table and header name.  So it should work now.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I changed the names (Textbox1.value -> itemid_dynamiclabel.caption) and the tablename[rowname] but it still doesn't read the table: "DesiredRange = nothing". How do I name/specify the table[row]?

Comment: Target.row will give you the row number selected as a long type.

Comment: Error: "Target = Empty"?